# Kusto join tables from different DB

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a requirement to join 2 tables in Kusto but they are in different Database under same cluster.

I can see the below Query works if the tables are in Same DB.

```html
Table1 | join (Table2) on CommonColumn, $left.Col1 == $right.Col2
```

But could you please tell me how do I join 2 tables in diff DB.

for example

1. DB1 - Table 1 - This is where I run the Query
2. DB2 - Table 2 - this is where I would like to take a join and I have the common column name - RunID

Comment: My first google hit appears to show how https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/cross-cluster-or-database-queries?pivots=azuredataexplorer `cluster("<cluster name>").database("<database name>").<table name>`

Comment: Thanks. I did check this one but this one is for the remote cluster. but in my case I have the DB in the same cluster.

Comment: So what if you use the same cluster name? Or exlcude the cluster piece altogether? PS it helps to add this information to the original question. Also if you encounter an error, post it.

Comment: In other words, does `database("DB2").Table2` work

Answer (score 2):

If you're running the query in the context of db1, then you can run a cross-db query like this:

```
Table1 // assuming Table1 is in db1
| join (database("db2").Table2) on CommonColumn, $left.Col1 == $right.Col2
```

If you don't know (or don't want to rely) on the database in the context of which the query runs, you can prefix all the tables with the relevant database name, like this:

```
database("db1").Table1
| join (database("db2").Table2) on CommonColumn, $left.Col1 == $right.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take the join with the below query

```html
| join kind = innerunique ( 
database("DB2").Table2) on $left.RunID == $right.RunID
```

Thanks